# Lua require relative path

Tags: lua

I can't load .Lua-files from relative paths.

This works:

2.lua

```
function Math( v1, v2 )
 return v1 + v2
end
```

1.lua

```
package.path = package.path .. ';C:/Users/Lukas/Desktop/lua/function/?.lua'
require("2")
print(Math(1,6))
```

This doesn't work:

```
package.path = package.path .. './function/?.lua;'
require("2")
print(Math(1,6))
```

Couldn't find any solution for my problem.

Comment: Please leave the original question as it was. Add solutions as answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing a `;` to separate the new path from the old one:

```
package.path = package.path .. ';./function/?.lua;'
```

`require` probably showed you this message:

```
no file './2.lua./function/2.lua'
```

which should have alerted you to the problem.

Comment: It works for me. You may need to start Lua in the directory containing `function`. I don't know how to do this in Windows, though.

Comment: The problem could be the Zerobrane Editor. I tried "lua 1.lua" on command line and it worked.

Comment: @LukasSchulig, if you are using ZeroBrane Studio, make sure you have the Project folder set to `C:/Users/Lukas/Desktop/lua/` as it's set as the current folder when your script is executed and the relative path you specified will be relative to that folder. When you start your script, you'll see `Program 'lua.exe' started in '<project folder>'` message, which shows what folder it is started in.

Answer (score 3):

```
package.path = package.path .. ';function/?.lua'
```

or

```
package.path = 'function/?.lua;' .. package.path
```

Up to you.